# Validate xml as memorystream against xsd as string

Tags: xml, vb.net, validation, xsd

I want to validate xml against **XSD** *(VB.NET)*. My function look like this:

```
Private Function ValidateXML(ByVal xml As MemoryStream, ByVal xsd As String) As    ArrayList
End Function
```

How can I do the validation when my xml is a memorystream/stream (I use stream because I don’t need to store the xml) and my xsd is a string (I get my xsd from a web servise as a string, and I do not need to store it in a file)?

Thanks a lot for all help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Schema

Module Module1

    Private isvalid As Boolean

    Sub Main()
        Dim xml As MemoryStream
        Dim xsd As String
        Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings()
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
        settings.Schemas.Add("Schema:name", xsd)
        AddHandler settings.ValidationEventHandler, AddressOf MyValidationEventHandler

        Dim v = XmlReader.Create(xml, settings)

        While (v.Read())

        End While

        If isValid Then
            Console.WriteLine("Document is valid")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Document is invalid")
        End If
    End Sub



    Public Sub MyValidationEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ValidationEventArgs)
        isValid = False
        Console.WriteLine("Validation event\n" + args.Message)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks! But in the line: settings.Schemas.Add("Schema:name", xsd) I have to put the URI to the schema, I want to use the string with the xsd. How can I do that?

Comment: In the xsd string you have you should have the namespace xmlns="urn:bookstore-schema" you should very easily be able to get that out. The xsd schema name and the xml schema name should match anyway else the xml will never validate, I think.

Comment: In my xsd I have xmlns:ttset="http://www.ttset.com/or" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema". What should I use?

Comment: the first one, read more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.schemas.aspx